# Stream through whole collection with mongodb native client and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, stream

I am desperately looking for a way to stream through a whole collection with node.js and the native mongodb driver. I am looking at this code:

```
var createAnalytics = function(db) {
  db.collection('changelog', function(err, changes) {
    assert.equal(null, err);

    var lastChange, index = 0;

    var changeCursor = changes
      .find({
        "activity": "patch",
        "entityOrRelationKind": "company",
        "customData._state": "published"
      })
      .sort({"userId": 1, "entityOrRelationId": 1})
      .stream();

    changeCursor.on('end', function() {
      console.log(index);
      db.close();
    });

    changeCursor.on('data', function(change) {
      index++;

      ...

      lastChange = change;
    });
  });
};
```

All I get though is just one batch (in my case here 1000 but if I set the batchSize to 5, I get 5). How can I get the next batch? I thought the streaming API is for iterating through the whole collection? What am I missing?

Thanks a million in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found it out myself and it is probably clear to most of you out there, but just for the sake of completeness: If you are using a compound search query like me in this case, you also have to create an index on that. Otherwise mongo would need to load the whole collection into memory and thus only returns as many documents as fit into approximately 1 MB.

This still leaves the question how you could get the next batch in above case. Anyone?